# Trying to center align using Table Cells

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this so this might be really stupid, but here goes.

I'm trying to vertical align a div to the middle of my page but it doesn't seem to be working. The text always loads in the top left corner?

```css
/*=======================================
                   HOME
    =======================================*/

#home {
  height: 100%;
}

#home-cover {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/bg-home.jpg");
}

#home-content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#home-content-box-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-heading h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin;
  20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Home -->
<section id="home">

  <div id="home-cover" class="bg-paralax animated fadeIn">
    <div id="home-content-box">
      <div id="home-conent-box-inner">
        <div id="home-heading" class="animated zoomIn">
          <h3>Watch Out <br> The Modern Responsive Website!
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="home-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="#work" role="button" title="View Our Work">View Our Work</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you have misspelled in html `home-content-box-inner` . you spelled `conent` , will that solve your issue ?

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You third div class is not correct "home-conent-box-inner" "instead of home-content-box-inner"

Comment: yup i was being an idiot and missed a "t"